# Knowledge Article's href is overridden for 'tel:' links

Tags: knowledge, articles, lightning-knowledge

When I try to insert a call link to an Article with this:

```
<a href="tel:+18475555555">1-847-555-5555</a>
```

On save, it converts automatically to

```
<a href="" target="_blank">1-847-555-5555</a>
```

this is causing issue to add support for directly start a call from articles

Comment: as usual, Salesforce support responded with article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.fields_using_html_editor.htm&type=5 
and so, 'tel:' as link is not supported. 
Its surprising that a CMS does not support all tags!

Comment: may as well add that as the accepted answer. Can include this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrJzAAK) that has a comment from the product manager about improving the rich text editor (unsure if that would entail supporting this protocol).

Comment: 12 years and the idea is still open with close to 14k points! just added my +10 there. thanks for the suggestion @KrisGoncalves